# What is the limit of the following function, as x approaches 0.

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the limit of the following function, as x approaches 0.

$$\displaystyle{\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{26x^3}{3}(ln(x)-\frac{1}{3}})$$

I try putting the equation in another way.

$$\frac{26}{3}\displaystyle{\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{ln(x)-\frac{1}{3}}{x^{-3}}}$$

I am stuck as to what to do for the next steps. My tutor told me to use L'Hospital's rule, but how can that be as both the denominator and numerator approaches different value as x approaches 0?

Comment: We need limit as $x$ approaches $0$ from the right, from the left is not possible. Let $y=1/x$ and L'Hospital's Rule will work fine.

Comment: With the rewrite, the denominator "approaches" $\infty$ and the numerator "approaches" $-\infty$, and the functions are nice, so L'Hospital's Rule applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the function inside the limit is not defined for $x\le 0$, so strictly the double-sided limit you wrote does not exist. However, you probably mean the right-hand limit, which is what I will work with here. (I see that @AndréNicolas beat me to this comment.)

Split the limit into

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{26x^3}{3}\ln x\right)-\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{26x^3}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{3}\right)$$

The right limit is clearly zero. Change the left one into

$$\frac{26}{3}\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\ln x}{x^{-3}}$$

and use L'Hôpital's rule on the limit.